# Recursing a 1D nested array to update parent nodes

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, recursion

I have a 1D nested array:

```
nestedObj: [
   { id: 1, parentId: null, taskCode: '12', taskName: 'Parent', duration: 0, assignee: '', crewCount: 0, startDate: null, endDate: null, dependencies: []},
   { id: 2, parentId: 1, taskCode: '12100', taskName: 'Child one', duration: 0, assignee: '', crewCount: 0, startDate: null, endDate: null, dependencies: []},
   { id: 3, parentId: 2, taskCode: '12200', taskName: 'SubChild one', duration: 0, assignee: '', crewCount: 0, startDate: null, endDate: null, dependencies: []},
   { id: 4, parentId: 1, taskCode: '12200', taskName: 'Child two', duration: 0, assignee: '', crewCount: 0, startDate: null, endDate: null, dependencies: []}
]
```

As per the above data structure, the tree view with `taskName` is stated below

```
-> Parent
        -> Child one
                   -> SubChild one
        -> Child two
```

Here is my question: when I update the `startDate` of a child, its immediate parent's `startDate` should be updated with the minimum `startDate` (of all its children) and this process should propagate till the root. And the vice versa for `endDate` (ie) the maximum `startDate` (of all its children). How can I achieve this using recursion?

Note: Assume the dates to be timestamps

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is a bit broad.  What problem did you encounter when trying to code it?

Comment: The structure is so flat that I am struggling to write the function that calls recursively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive function you need will look something like this:

```js
methods: {
    adjustParent(item) {
      if (!item.parentId) return;   // top-level, exit

      const parent = this.nestedObj.find(o => o.id === item.parentId);
      const children = this.nestedObj.filter(o => o.parentId === item.parentId);

      parent.startDate = Math.min.apply(null, children.map(o => o.startDate));

      this.adjustParent(parent);  // recurse
    }
}
```

You could call it on `change` for example:

```html
<div v-for="item in nestedObj">
  <input type="text" v-model="item.startDate" @change="adjustParent(item)" />
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/mLog27ax/)

Comment: I won't write the whole feature, but this pseudo-implementation of the minimum `startDate` recursion should give you what you need to get started

Comment: This answer really saved my day. Thank you so much @Dan